# Automating FillDown not working

Tags: excel, vba

Code currently looks like this:

```
Sub PriceChange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  If Not ws.Name = "Cover" Then
  i = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


ws.Range("K13").Formula = "=IF(AND(J13<>0,J14<>0),IFERROR(J14/LOOKUP(2,1/(J$13:J13<>0),J$13:J13)-1,""Bad""),""Bad"")"
'Set sourceRange = ws.Range("K13")
Range("K14").Select
Range("K14").Copy
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K14:K" & Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row)
'Set fillRange = ws.Range("K14:K" & i)
'sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
ws.Range("H13").Formula = "=IF(AND(G13<>0,G14<>0),IFERROR(G14/LOOKUP(2,1/(G$13:G13<>0),G$13:G13)-1,""Bad""),""Bad"")"
'    Set sourceRange = ws.Range("H13")
    Range("H14").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H14:H" & Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row)

'Set fillRange = ws.Range("H14:H" & i)
'sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
    End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I have left in the commented out sections, as it USED to work using those. I had to change a few formulae and the filldown now only populates the top row (i.e. it doesnt work). I want it to fill the entire range (dynamic). The closest i got it to do was the top 2 rows, but am starting to go around in circles.

Any ideas as to where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You have columsn `k`, `h`. So Which one is not doing the `autofill`? or both?

Comment: both :( whether it goes in H13 or H14 doesnt matter, as long as it does one shorter or longer the other end. (as H12 always is blank), taking the % change between H12 and H13 always gives a silly number so it is disregarded.

Comment: this macro is in a looping script. I create new sheets every time, and want the formula input and filled down automatically each time. It just refuses to fill down and i think its because the first formula references rows 13 and 14. If i manually do the filldown it only does those 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't `select` columns for the sake of performance... You can do the work by referring to the `range object`

Try the following please:

```
'--change the sheet accordingly

Sheets1(1).Range("K15").Formula = Sheets(1).Range("K14").Formula
Sheets(1).Range("K15").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("K15:K" & i)
```

You may add the following `Sub routine` to test out your sheet. Perhaps there's is an issue with your `loop`. `Offset`, `Resize` are better tips to improve your code. You may even not use `With`..

```
Sub fillFormulasDown()
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '--if you have a password use this line
    Set wkSheet = Sheets(1)
    'wkSheet.Unprotect Password:="urpassword"
    '--otherwise use this line
    wkSheet.Unprotect

    lRow = wkSheet.Range("G" & wkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '--test with a small formula
    wkSheet.Range("K13").Formula = "=IF(J13<>0,1,0)"

      With wkSheet.Range("K14")
        .Formula = Range("K13").Formula
        .AutoFill Destination:=.Offset(0, 0).Resize(lRow)
      End With

    wkSheet.Unprotect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: no joy, it =just refuses to fill down, is there any way of circumventing the autofill? getting excel to populate each of those cells with the formula, but dynamically?

Comment: solution: issue was with the i = range(xxxxx), needs to be i = ws.range(xxxxx)

Comment: @Cylen sorry I was away. Check on the updated `Sub route` and **see if it works just for one column**, then you can expand it to the others. And also make sure the sheet is `not protected`.

Comment: It's recommended to have `explicit` referencing :) Glad you worked it out.